# Find if a decimal is larger than four places

Tags: c#, string, vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to validate a form in C# and need to determine if a decimal place from a string is larger than 4 places.

Currently, the past validation in VB was:

```
Len(Mid(pAnnualFee, (InstrRev(pAnnualFee, ".") + 1), Len(pAnnualFee))) > 4
```

How would this be converted to c# in a concise way, or even the way it is now using C#'s equivalent of InstrRev and mid?

Comment: Understandable that you want to just convert that code, but I would ditch it, especially if working with money. Its culture-specific, so if somebody uses it from a culture that uses a comma as a decimal delimiter, then this function will fail. For example, $150,20 is the same as $150.20 depending on culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse(pReturn);
if (Decimal.Round(d, 4) != d)
```

Comment: This won't work because pReturn is clearly a string and there is no overload of Decimal.Round that takes a string as the first argument.

Comment: @Joe:- Didnt see that pReturn was string. Updated my answer!

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but I can't just round. I need to validate that a fee is correctly input.  If that fee is rounded, it might not be the same.

Comment: @user1093111:- Didnt you ask how to check if the string is having 4 places of decimal? The Round function is used to check that only by comparing the rounded value with the original value. If the string will have more or less number of decimal places then the check will fail which is what you want..isn't it?

Comment: @RahulTripathi oh, yeah.  I misunderstood, I thought you meant rounding explicitly.

Comment: @RahulTripathi thanks.  I went with this, it was simple enough for another person to understand what the logic was doing. All I had to do was wrap it in another if statement that performed a tryparse to make sure there were only numbers and not letters.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use the solution in @fix_likes_coding's answer.

However, while the Decimal struct doesn't have a method to get the number of decimals, you could call [Decimal.GetBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) to extract the binary representation, then use the integer value and scale to compute the number of decimals.

This would probably be faster than formatting as a string, though you'd have to be processing an awful lot of decimals to notice the difference.

Try something like this ( as example ) :

```
decimal argument = 123.456m;
int count = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(argument)[3])[2];
```

then just :

```
if(count>4)
{
//your code
}
```

Comment: What does the [3] and the [2] do?

Comment: @user1093111 no problem :)